# How to do create a list of candidate objects in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to find an object that best fits some data. The way I'm doing it is by creating a list of objects, each one tries to fit the data in a different way, and then at the end select the one that best fits the data.
To do this, I created a list of these objects, and I want them all to be the same at the beginning, to be equal to an original object. The way I naively did this was just:

```
List <tryObject> tryObjects = new List<tryObject>();

for(int i = 0; i< numberOfDifferentTries; i++)
{
    tryObjects.Add(new truPbject());
    tryObjects[i].dataObject = originalDataObject;
    tryObjects[i].blabla = blablu;
    ...Other assignments
    tryObjects[i].TryToFitTheData();
}
//Select which tryObject in tryObjects[] fits the data best and return it.
```

However, I discovered that this doesn't work as I want, because each `tryObjects[i].dataObject` is just a reference to the `originalDataObject`, so whenever I change each of the `dataObjects`, all of the change, plus the original one.

I understand what I'd need in this case is a deep copy. However, all the methods to do so I found either use `IClonable` or special methods to hard copy, such as serialization, which take a bit effort or can bring headaches.

So, since C# doesn't provide a simple way to do this, I assume it's because it's not designed to solve this problem in this way.

So, my question is, what is the best way to do what I want to do in C#, by following the way it wants me to do things?

Comment: In order to know how best to do this, you'll need to explain why you were trying to do it this way to begin with. What are you trying to achieve (at a higher level than "selecting from a list of objects, the one that best fits the data"?

Comment: "since C# doesn't provide a simple way to do this, I assume it's because it's not designed to solve this problem in this way" This assumption is wrong: C# doesn't provide a simple way to make a copy of an object because there is no easy way to guess how deep or how shallow you would like to go when copying your object's components. Follow any of the recommendations that you found, it's not too much work.

Comment: At first glance, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the way you are trying to use your objects. I suspect the problem may be in the way your originalDataObject's class is implemented but, that is just a guess because you aren't showing the imlementation of any of your classes.

Answer (score 1):

> So, since C# doesn't provide a simple way to do this, I assume it's because it's not designed to solve this problem in this way.

That is wrong. There is a way to do this and you described it well: use `ICloneable` for shallow copying or another method like serializing to do deep cloning. `ICloneable` is here from the beginning of the framework and very commonly used.

I would prefer using `ICloneable` as much as possible. It is quite easy to write and easy in use.

This is a template I always use, since it returns the typed result of `Clone`, which might come in handy:

```
public class SomeClass : ICloneable
{
    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return this.Clone();
    }

    public SomeClass Clone()
    {
        SomeClass otherInstance = new SomeClass();

        // do the cloning here
        otherInstance.Property = this.Property;
        // end

        return otherInstance;
    }
}
```